# pathForResource returns nil for all pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, bundle

I upgraded to xcode 8 and did a pod install, now all pods which depend on its own assets are failing to find bundle path. Codes like this in all pods

```
self.assetBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *bundlePath = [self.assetBundle pathForResource:@"some_Pod_name" ofType:@"bundle"];
```

Bundle path returns nil then obviously my app crashes in the pod. 
assetBundle returns this

```
 po self.assetBundle
NSBundle </Users/user1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0ACF195-A1C8-4DA6-96B5-9F9824DF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6F11AC53-0D13-4CD8-9DB0-77BE8C54C9/myapp.app> (loaded)
```

There must be something in settings that I couldn't figure out. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I needed to uncheck "Run script only when installing" for pods resources.